# Dynamically load images before render

Tags: reactjs, webpack, axios

I've browsed a lot of questions but I can't find a correct answer to this. Say I have an `images` folder, and I want to display a specific image in there. I don't know the name of the image to be displayed, it's returned by a RESTful API along with many other details on that object I'm displaying.

I considered a few alternatives to do that:

- Load all images no matter what, then only render the ones I need. I found this in a few places, but I think it's pretty heavy, isn't it?
- Use `webpack` to `require` the file I need on the fly.

The second option seems to be the best here. However, when I do:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://url.to/my/RESTful/api')
       .then(res => {
           this.setState(res.data);
       });
}
render() {
    var pic = require(`../images/${this.state.picture}`)
    return (<img src={pic} alt="some name" />)
);
```

React complains it can't load `undefined`, because it starts rendering before the axios call gets done. Another alternative is thus to display a loader while the call is being done, or preventing rendering in general. But my question is rather: what's the best practice here? Should I have a loader on every page loading dynamic data? I suppose I'm missing something, which is why I'm reaching out. How do you usually do that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
class ImageLoader extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.data = {
            data: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get("http://url.to/my/RESTful/api").then(res => {
            this.setState({ data: res.data });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.data
            ? <img
                  src={require(`../images/${this.state.data.picture}`)}
                  alt="some name"
              />
            : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That'd work since we wouldn't render anything until it's loaded. My question is then: is it the best practice to create an image loader? Especially, the RESTful API URL is not static and depends on the kind of object I'm loading. Would you suggest to serve images separately and use a generic image loader as you proposed, maybe?

Comment: I would certainly recommend serving the images separately as this will help make your app scalable long-term and considering the future is a good design principle.  You could certainly make the above code generic by passing the URL as a prop like `axios.get(this.props.url)`. Not sure if that helped or not lol.

Comment: It is really helping me understanding how I should be thinking, yes! And thanks for the recommendations. I think I'll create an image loader like you proposed, but maybe pass only the image name and if it's undefined it returns nothing. That should work for now, and easily upgradable in the future when I'll rely on a CDN.

Comment: Sounds like a plan! Glad I could help. Happy coding broseph =]